# Sending Files Directly through phone lines

Tags: sendfile

As you know we can use our ADSL modems to send/receive data with high bandwidth through our phone line to/from ISP servers. I'm interested to write a program to use this capability of ADSL modem to send/receive files directly between computers (like Hyper Terminal application which was used for 56k serial modems). Is it possible? Also I want to know does it need governmental support or not? :)

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

While this is definitly possible (at least with the Alcatel ADSL modems), it is not worth the hassle. Some random points - please mind that this is written from a european POV, things might be a little different in the USA.

- Carriers are not amused, if you change the configuration of your modem. Some will call it "hacking" and disconnect you.
- It is not possible, to use the modem for both (Internet access and file transfer) at the same time.
- It won't work between modems on different carrier networks or even in different LM segments of the same carrier - the ADSL signal is terminated at the multiplexer in your carrier's LM switch. It does however work between modems attached to the same multiplexer.

For your problem, the solution ist to use a TCP connection instead of a fake serial - even HyperTerminal can do that AFAIR